# rule dotnet_style_namespace_match_folder doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, editorconfig

My EditorConfig

```
# top-most EditorConfig file, hierarchy search will stop in this file
root = true

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Coding styles
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Dotnet code style settings:
[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0055.severity = error
dotnet_style_namespace_match_folder = true:error
```

Class I test against. Namespace should match the structure and be equal to `ConsoleApp1`

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.NotHere
{
    public class Class
    {
        private int X { get; set; } = 0;

        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Solution builds without errors, namespace is not highlighted in VS.
I have checked on fresh console project in .net 6 in VS 2022 and 2019 with latest updates

VS 2022 Community Version 17.1.1

VS 2019 Professional Version 16.11

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules#dotnet-namespace-options) says it should be available in both IDE, but I cannot make it works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [IDE0130](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/aeb9006e67cb50289d169a00c621ebbce7df9d0b/src/VisualStudio/Core/Def/CodeCleanup/readme.md#how-editorconfig-options-and-diagnostics-ids-all-fit-together) diagnostic id:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0130.severity = error
```

Comment: If i add this to editorconfig and run dotnet format, it gives the following error, what am i doing wrong?  ``` Unhandled exception: System.NotSupportedException: Changing document properties is not supported ...```

Comment: @ManzurAlahi TBH have not used `dotnet format` much especially with the editor config settings. Do you have a [mre]? Can you post it somewhere (like github)?

Comment: I'm getting the same error with this diagnostic rule. If I add --exclude-diagnostic IDE0130 to the dotnet format command it passes. So something must be up with the autofix for this rule.

Comment: @mikesigs is there any chance you are using Rider/Resharper? If yes - then try adding `resharper_check_namespace_highlighting = none` to the `.editorconfig`.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52991

No longer planned for deprecation

Comment: @Clumpsypenguin that are good news!